# C# How to create a Dataset instance with relations between two tables

Tags: c#, winforms, postgresql, foreign-keys, relation

Well thats my problem. I'm trying to query a remote postgresql DB and then fill TWO RELATED instanced tables with the result, so i can fill a form that displays information for both tables. Doing this with a single table was simple, but now i'm unable to correctly define relationships. I'm getting the “Object reference not set to an instance of an object” error What im doing wrong?

Relation is "components/provider_id" to "provider/id" so i can fill provider fields automatically in the components forms (while doing a search query).

Heres my code:

```
OdbcDataAdapter sdata = new OdbcDataAdapter(//Query string whatever);
OdbcDataAdapter sdata2 = new OdbcDataAdapter(//Query string whatever);

DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //new dataset instance

DataTable dtbl = new DataTable();  //two new instanced tables
DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable();

sdata.Fill(dtbl);  //fill both tables with each query data
sdata2.Fill(dtbl2);

ds.Tables.Add(dtbl); //Add those tables to DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dtbl2);

//So now im tring to create a relation between both tables
// im getting "“Object reference not set to an instance of an object”

 DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",  
 ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id"],
 ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id_prov_comp"]);
```

Also I suppose that after that i will need some advice on creating some keys for the columns.

Can I get a little help? Please keep in mind that im fairly new to programing in general and c# in particular.

Comment: i don't think your tables have names `"dtbl"` and `"dtbl2"`. they are variables names. and i think you can safely use them like this: `dtbl.Columns["id"], dtbl2.Columns["id_prov_comp"]` (check that those columns have been created)

Comment: does your dataset contain a table with the name "dtbl" ? No, you did not set the table name. Therefore `ds.Tables["dtbl"]` does not work. You can, however, set the names once you have added the tables to the DataSet, and then use them from then on. `ds.Tables[0].TableName = "dtbl";`

Comment: [Creating and configuring datasets in Visual Studio](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/04y282hb.aspx)

Comment: Added the tablenames. Relation is created but now got primary key error, i've edited original post.

Comment: Each post should be dedicated to a single question. Now you are editing your question and each time you share a new `Exception`. This way, you may invalidate answers which users posted for your previous edits. You can  ask a question about *How to create a dataset instance with relations between two tables* and then share what you have tried and share the exception or problem and ask for a solution.

Comment: Also answer to users posts under they posts using comments, yo don't need to edit the question to reflect the changes that you made.

Comment: Sorry im new to Stackoverflow, i've just restored original post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should add the relation to [`Relations`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ay82azad(v=vs.110).aspx) collection of your `DataSet`:

```
DataSet ds = new DataSet(); //new dataset instance
DataTable dtbl = new DataTable("Your Parent TableName");  //two new instanced tables
DataTable dtbl2 = new DataTable("Your Child TableName");
sdata.Fill(dtbl);  //fill both tables with each query data
sdata2.Fill(dtbl2);
ds.Tables.Add(dtbl); //Add those tables to DataSet
ds.Tables.Add(dtbl2);
ds.Relations.Add("Your Relation Name",dtbl.Columns["id"], dtbl2.Columns["id_prov_comp"]);

//or
//ds.Relations.Add(ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id"], ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id_prov_comp"]);

ds.AcceptChanges();
```

Comment: added tables names and ds.AcceptChanges. But still getting a blanck form.

Comment: you are add relation. but not the relation add to dataset.             ds.Relations.Add("Your Relation Name",dtbl.Columns["id"], dtbl2.Columns["id_prov_comp"]);
or
            DataRelation dr = new DataRelation("provcomp",
ds.Tables["dtbl"].Columns["id_prov_comp"],
ds.Tables["dtbl2"].Columns["id"]);

            ds.Relations.Add(dr);

Comment: Adding that relation to Dataset solved the problem (plus naming tables correctly as explained above. Thanks.